# Python proxy authentication with Requests and Urlib2

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Does anyone have any ideas on why the Urlib2 version returns the webpage, while the Requests version returns a connection error:

> [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party
>   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

**Urllib2 code (Working):**

```
import urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://login:password@proxy1.com:80'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
wPage = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
print wPage.read();
```

**Requests code (Not working - Errno 10060):**

```
import requests

proxy = {"http": "http://login:password@proxy1.com:80"}
wPage = requests.get('http://www.google.com/', proxies=proxy)
print wPage.text
```

The requests version returns intranet webpages, but gives an error on internet pages.

I am running Python 2.7

*** Edit ***

Based on m170897017's suggestion, I looked for differences in the GET requests. The only difference was in Connection and Proxy-Connection.

Urllib2 version:

> header: Connection: close
>
> header: Proxy-Connection: close

Requests version :

> header: Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> header: Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

I forced the Requests version to close both of those connections by modifying the header

```
header = {
   "Connection": "close",
   "Proxy-Connection": "close"
}
```

The GET request for both now match, however the Requests version still does not work.

Comment: Sniff packets sent by different program to see if HTTP GET is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '1.1.1.1:9090'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
datum = response.read().decode("UTF-8")
response.close()
print datum
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the response, I appreciate it, however it was the Requests code that isn't working on internet pages - I probably should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

A little late... but for future reference this line:
    proxy = {"http": "http://login:password@proxy1.com:80"}

should also have a second key/value pair for https, even if it's not going to be used.

Also there is an awesome requests module called proxy requests that does something very similar:

```
pip3 install proxy-requests
```

https://pypi.org/project/proxy-requests/